# What should i answer to governor limit question in intervies

Tags: apex, visualforce

Please guide to get good knowledge on Apex code writing and visual force.

Answer (score 1):

We all have been in this situation before to know where to start with :)

I would recommend you to going through the [Force.com Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals) and [Intro to Point & Click App Development](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-point-click-app-development--ud162). This will give you an idea on Core Salesforce Fundamentals.

Then you can  go through the [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en). These modules will be the good starting point for learning APEX and Visualforce.

Here are the guide links to start with,

[Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro.htm)

[Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm)

A [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apex/apex_governor_limits.htm) link to know about Governor Limit on Salesforce

Comment: Thank you Devendra, i will go through the developer guide.